# Printf with arrays

Tags: arrays, c

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsirT.png)

Beginner:
Trying to make it print all the elements in my array, when i tell it for example in the image print element 7 it does fine if i try to use my loop and replace the 7 with i it just says segmentation fault (core dumped),
I tried using

```
printf("%d", i, bubble[i]);
```

but when i added the extra i it told me there was too many arguments but i swear u can have 3 within printf.
As said im new to C and coding all together so please bare this in mind, any help appreciated thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please do not post code as an image - [reasoning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Copy it as formatted text into the question.

Comment: If you want to print more than one number you have to use the correct specifiers, e.g.: `printf("%d %d", i, bubble[i]);`

Comment: `printf` can take arbitrarily many arguments. Each argument after the format string has to correspond to a conversion specifier in the format string.

Answer (score 1):

You need to to use a 2nd %d

For example:

```
printf("%d %d\n", i, bubble[i]);
```

Will return:

```
0 3
1 7
2 4
3 3
4 8
5 9
6 2
```

But as you see it leaves out the last numer, so you need to remove `(lenght - 1)` and just use `for(i = 0; i < lenght; i++)`